# In app purchase Alert Box orientation changes to portrait when app resumed

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am having a weird problem.
My game is all landscape. I have a inapp purchase button in my app. When I tap on that button I see the normal alert button in landscape mode. But when I press the home button and reopen the app, then tap on the inapp purchase, the orientation of the Alert box changes to portait.

I have no idea why this is happening. Have you guys ever had this issue? Any ideas or suggestions welcomed!

Comment: Is this happening in the simulator, on the device, both?  I've seen this kind of problem dealing with GameKit alerts and windows combined with cocos2d.  While the simulator flips back to portrait when I dismiss a dialog, it works fine on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation animated:NO];
```

It appears these alert views orient themselves based on the status bar (whether status bar is visible or not)