# StoreKit Dialog Orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In app purchase Alert Box orientation changes to portrait when app resumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233804/in-app-purchase-alert-box-orientation-changes-to-portrait-when-app-resumed)

I have an app that is permanently in landscape orientation. All my custom UIAlertViews display in the correct orientation, but the default StoreKit dialogs (the ones that Apple display automatically, such as the dialog that asks for your username and password) only display in Portrait orientation. Does anyone know if there is any way to force these UIAlertViews to display in Landscape?

Cheers!